# Nestjs Vue azure passport authentification

Tags: vuejs3, nest, passport-azure-ad

I'm working on a SSO authentification using azure ad passport.

Here is my backend code :

azure strategy:

```
@Injectable()
export class AzureADStrategy extends PassportStrategy(OIDCStrategy , 'azure-ad') {
  constructor() {
    super({
      clientID:clientID,
      clientSecret: clientSecret,
      identityMetadata: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantID}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`,
      redirectUrl: redirectURL,
      responseType: 'code',
      responseMode: 'query',
      allowHttpForRedirectUrl : true,
      scope: ['profile', 'User.Read'],
    });
  }
```

authenfitication controller :

```
@Get('/login')
  @UseGuards(AzureAdAuthGuard)
 login()  {
    // This route will initiate the Azure AD login process
    // The actual login flow will be handled by the guard
  }
```

Frontend :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <button @click="login">azure</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
  import axios from 'axios'
  const login = async () => {
    window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/auth/login'
```

What happens is that the @Azureguard on the login initiates the sso authentification, and does redirect toward the redirect uri specified in the strategy configuration, but what should i do after this to get the user info  ??????

Thank you